# How can I forward certain emails using office365

Tags: email, office365, forwarding

I want to forward messages that have a certain subject (lets say "she sells seashells") to a coworker. I do not want to forward all my messages - just those that have "she sells seashells" in the subject. I have Office365 (https://outlook.office.com/owa) and I have admin privileges. Here is what I have tried:

1. got to settings (gear icon at the top right)
2. click on *Mail* under *Your app settings* at the bottom
3. click *Inbox and sweep rules* under *Automatic Processing*
4. create a new inbox rule:

[image: office365 forward rule]

Its not working. Nothing is being forwarded.

Comment: Are you an Administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that works is to configure this in the *Exchange admin centre*:

1. go to the *Office365 app list* page (https://www.office.com)
2. click on the *Admin* icon (https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home)
3. click on the *Admin centres* at the bottom of the options on the left
4. click on Exchange (https://outlook.office365.com/ecp)
5. click on *mail flow* from the options on the left
6. click the *rules* tab at the top
7. click create a new rule
8. on the *Apply this rule if...* dropdown, choose *The subject or body includes* and enter the phrase `she sells seashells` (do not use any quotes)
9. on the *Do the following* dropdown, choose *Bcc the message to* and select an email address
10. click Save
11. wait an unspecified amount of time for this rule to take effect (it is definitely not immediate)

I know Bcc is not the same as forwarding but this is the closest you can come to the intended functionality.